# how can I show that for projection matrix $P^2 = P$ without applying trigonometry

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am following MIT 18.06 [lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_Ac6KiQ1t0&list=PL221E2BBF13BECF6C&index=33) on linear algebra and would like to understand how one can show that $P^2 = P$ for a projection matrix.

I understand that for 2-d case:

$P = \frac{a a^t}{a^t a}$

$P^2 = \frac{a a^t}{a^t a} \frac{a a^t}{a^t a}$

I assume I should easily show it by using some properties of transpose matrices/vectors, but I couldn't quite figure out how to derive it.
(I am familiar with the proof that relies on trigonometric formulas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking is indeed just some matrix calculation:

First note that $a^ta = |a|^2$ and that matrix multiplication is associative both with respect to scalars and the matrices themselves and that scalars can be put in front:

$$P^2 = \frac{a a^t}{a^t a} \frac{a a^t}{a^t a}=\frac 1{|a|^4}(a a^t)(a a^t)$$$$=\frac 1{|a|^4}(a \underbrace{(a^ta)}_{=|a|^2} a^t)=\frac{1}{|a|^2}aa^t=P$$

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to see this is to think about what a projection does. A projection map $P = P_{U}$ maps every vector $x$ into the subspace $U$. In particular, for any vector $u \in U$, $P(u) = u$. Then since you know that $P(x) \in U$ for all $x$, we have that for all $x$,
$$P^{2}(x) = P(P(x)) = P(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

A projection matrix in dimension $n$ is similar to an always vanishing matrix except that it has $p \le n$ $1$ for the first $p$ diagonal entries.

And for such a matrix it is clear that $P^2=P$.